# How to display on page Data Source

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list

Please help me. I have some SharePoint list's (they have the same structure - columns etc, only data is different). I'm searching for a method to display them on page like one big list.

In SharePoint Designer I have found function to merge them in to one element/source: Data Sources -> Linked Data Source

[image]

But now I can't find any way to display those in to the page.

It will be perfect if I can display them like list view or something similar.